# Wildfly classpath Isolation, and older version of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly-8

Wildfly has classpath isolation ( [No more jar hell!](http://wildfly.org/about/) ) , so can I expect my application to work correctly, given that it is packaged with older version of hibernate ( 3.6.0.Final ),without interference with the one that ships with wildfly 8  ?

Has anybody faced any issues having older version of hibernate running with Wildfly ?

Comment: What are the other technologies you are using? If other technologies does not have compatibility  issues with your hibernate version, you can use hibernate 3.6.0. If you are using Seam 2.3.1 then you should use hibernate 4.x(4.2.0 is preferred). Please post the other technologies used in your project so that I can provide the exact answer.

Comment: The other technologies are Servlet 2.5,Spring 3.2.x

Comment: You can use hibernate 3.6.0 by excluding the wildfly provided default hibernate(4.3.0). Please follow the below link.  https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose wildfly9 , and deployed my application with small changes on web side, but did no change was required  on the hibernate side,and it is working fine so far.